Axlmp.exe not found error in Visual Studio 2012
"C:\\Builds\\PremiumStore\\checkout\\PremiumStore.sln" (default target) (1) -\>
"C:\\Builds\\PremiumStore\\checkout\\Web\\PremiumStoreWeb.csproj" (default target) (37) -\>
(ResolveComReferences target) -\>
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\12.0\\bin\\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2151,5):  
error MSB3091: Task failed because "AxImp.exe" was not found, or the correct Microsoft  
Windows SDK is not installed.
The task is looking for "AxImp.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\WinSDK-  NetFx40Tools-x86.

I tried solutions in the following link but not worked for me, I installed both SDK 8.0 and 8.1, still getting the same error.

Any reason why you use such an old and unsupported version of VisualStudio?
